# What is its radius of convergence of this series?

Tags: power-series

How can I find the radius of convergence of the following ?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}(z-\pi i)^n $$

The problem is that it involves the complex number $\pi i$, and that is giving me a lot of trouble.

Here is how I have gone this far:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{n^n}(z-\pi i)=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n (z-\pi i)$$

Is the radius of convergence then $\frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: Yes, it is $\frac 1 e$.

Comment: You are completely right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius $\pi i$ is not a problem. It is the center of your disc of convergence.